# Nearest location from current location in map in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

Have a button on a mapview which is used to calculate the nearest location from the locations i have plotted on map. I have applied some code but when i click the button the app crashes by giving this error,

> [__NSDictionaryI coordinate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174e61b40
>       2017-10-31 15:20:00.434548 GuardsAutoZone[735:114166] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI coordinate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174e61b40'
>       *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1937d11b8 0x19220855c 0x1937d8268 0x1937d5270 0x1936ce80c 0x10011cec8 0x1996bbd30 0x1996bbcb0 0x1996a6128 0x1996bb59c 0x1996bb0c4 0x1996b6328 0x199686da0 0x199e7075c 0x199e6a130 0x19377eb5c 0x19377e4a4 0x19377c0a4 0x1936aa2b8 0x19515e198 0x1996f17fc 0x1996ec534 0x1000fc994 0x19268d5b8)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

My code is this, i'm in doubt that my code is right for finding nearest location or not? The code i used is,

```
- (IBAction)nearLocation:(id)sender {
CLLocation *userLocation = self.mapView.userLocation.location;
NSMutableDictionary *distances = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (MapPin *obj in locations) {
    CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:obj.coordinate.latitude longitude:obj.coordinate.longitude];
    CLLocationDistance distance = [loc distanceFromLocation:userLocation];

    NSLog(@"Distance from Annotations - %f", distance);

    [distances setObject:obj forKey:@( distance )];


}

NSArray *sortedKeys = [distances allKeys];
NSLog(@"List %@",sortedKeys);
//NSArray *closestKeys = [sortedKeys subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, MIN(3, sortedKeys.count))];

 // NSArray *closestAnnotations = [distances objectsForKeys:closestKeys notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];


}
```

the error screen shot is ,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7UvU.png)

Comment: `obj` seems to be a `NSDictionary`, not a `MapPin` object. Check `[obj class]`. Why? That depends on how `locations` is initialized/populated. Without that code, hard to say what's wrong.

Comment: locations are instialize as an array of static latitude and longitude. @Larme

Comment: `for (MapPin *obj in locations){NSLog(@"[obj class]: %@", [obj class]);}`, what does this give you?

Answer (score 0):

Use this set of code to get the distance between two latitude and longitude.

In **Objective C**

```
@class CLLocation

CLLocation *location1 =[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[@"23.039698" doubleValue] longitude:[@"77.571663" doubleValue]];
CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[@"23.0422" doubleValue] longitude:[@"72.5644" doubleValue]];
CLLocationDistance distanceMeter = [location distanceFromLocation:location2];
```

And in **Swift**

```
import CoreLocation

let location1 = CLLocation(latitude: 5.0, longitude: 5.0)
let location2 = CLLocation(latitude: 5.0, longitude: 3.0)

let distanceInMeters = location1.distance(from: location2)
```

The above code will give you the distance in meters.

Once you will get the distance between the two annotation through the coordinate then you can implement the same as per your requirement.

Comment: How can i take out distance from the array of latitude and logitude i have given static from the current location? How to run such a loop? @

Deepraj Chowrasia

Comment: how does your array look like..give the output of the array where you have stored your values

Comment: it is like this ,  locations=@[@{@"name":@"DHA Lahore",
                           @"lat":@"31.500855",
                           @"long":@"74.420502"},
                         @{@"name":@"Thokar Niaz Baig, Lahore",
                           @"lat":@"31.466606",
                           @"long":@"74.235498"},
                         @{@"name":@"Model Town, Lahore",
                           @"lat":@"31.471311",
                           @"long":@"74.319133"},];
@ Deepraj Chowrasia

Comment: run a basic for loop and keep the lat, long field in a separate array or whatsoever and use it accordingly

Comment: actually i'm confused in it how to run that loop and get check on each lat and long distance from current location, if u can guide it plz? @Deepraj Chowrasia

Answer (score 0):

It seems `locations` is an array of `NSDictionary`. In the `for` loop you cast the elements to `MapPin*` but that just makes the compiler happy. Accessing `obj.coordinate.latitude` will call selector `coordinate` on object `obj`. And the exception tells us its an NSDictionary object.

Check what kind of object `locations` really is at runtime and change your code accordingly.

Comment: actually locations is an array of latitude and longitude which i have declare in viewDidload. I want to run a loop in which the distance from current location to the latitude and logitude given should be fetch in an array. @D.Mika

Comment: I suggest to show the code where `locations` is initialized. It just seems to be a matter of how you access the objects in that array.